# Wage Negotiation

Tags: salary, negotiation, review

I work for a Czech technology company and am going through my annual review. Despite a glowing report from those I work for and with my pay is being frozen for another year. The sum affect of this and other freezes is a double digit percentage reduction in my real wage (after inflation).

The company justifies this by arguing that my wage matches the information they have for international and local wages and my relative position within the team I work in. Basically a bunch of unchallengeable averages to justify paying me less each year.

I'm pretty sure that the only way I will get a raise is as I'm walking at the door to another job, but I'd rather not leave for family reasons. Something I'm guessing they are relying on. It's a shame that it has come down to 'leverage' but in the mean time it would be good to know whether anyone has some useful arguments to undermine their arbitrary metric?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: You've said it yourself. You have two realistic alternatives: Leave or accept being paid less. If they know that you won't leave, they won't increase your salary. Why should they? Maybe, if you could increase your "relative position" in your team ...

Comment: You could also potentially use another offer to negotiate a raise, but only if you're willing to leave and I wouldn't consider that a long-term solution - [Do I mention a competing offer when negotiating a raise?](//workplace.stackexchange.com/q/33457)

Comment: _I'd rather not leave for family reasons_ If your company knew about that, you are unlikely going to get a raise. I will vote to "Leave Open" with the hope that somebody may be able to come up with a solution for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

It really does come down to leverage. You could dispute their wage averages and argue that you are being paid below rate in your market, but unless you actually have a better offer then you are stuck. Could you remote work for a better paying firm and avoid moving your family?

Answer (score 0):

You can argue until you're blue in the face, this is not a decision that is based on logic or on the arguments you are provided. The 'arguments' and 'reasons' they give you are nothing but excuses. Even the best company will generally pay you the least amount they feel they can get away with. There may be some legitimate reasons why they won't give you the desired raise but in the large majority of cases they're simply not going to give you one as long as they think they can get away with it.

So how do you break through this pattern? The answer is that you have to be perceived as willing to leave over this. You don't have to use threatening language, simply stating your position will be enough.

> I understand your reasons for denying me a raise but the simple fact is that if I don't get it, I'll have to start looking for a new job if I want to be able to keep providing for my family. I like working here because [reasons] but that's not as important as providing for my family is.

The answer to this is probably going to be some variation on "I'll see what we can do".

Be prepared for the answer to be "Sorry, nothing can be done, you're not getting a raise". Even if you *do* get the pay raise, be prepared to find a new job in the medium term, because squeezing the raise out of them when they really didn't want to give it to you usually raises negative emotions. While personal situations will often limit your options, they shouldn't be zero. You may be forced to take an undesirable one if you are to continue providing for your family.

Having said that, you'd be surprised at what suddenly becomes possible when an employee the company really wants to keep is threatening to leave. Frozen budgets can suddenly open up, or suddenly you might 'be able to get the raise if you keep your mouth shut about it because it might cause issues with morale'. If you *do* get a promise of a raise, get in writing how much of a raise you will be getting and starting when, then assess for yourself how likely you think it is that the promise will be kept or if it's just a tactic to keep you long enough for them to find a replacement willing to do the job for the money they're willing to pay.

If this seems cynical, remember that companies often feel that they are unique and that employees should be happy to get to work there. Management tends to feel that they know pretty well what people's services are worth and by providing those services at the price they are paying you and your colleagues are confirming those beliefs. Management can get so convinced of this belief that they'll let their best employees walk out the door or even fire them, thinking that they'll just find someone new or even someone better. It's only when the market proves them wrong that they'll grudgingly consider that they might have been wrong and even then, usually some poor fool will come along that *is* willing to take the offered pay, once more strengthening their belief.

Comment: [Should employees threaten resignation to get better benefits?](//workplace.stackexchange.com/q/70788) Sugar-coating is unlikely to make it seem like less of a threat.

Comment: Just remember that the only threat is an actual, valid, waiting to be signed by you contract from another company.

Comment: @Dukeling I wasn't advocating sugar-coating, I was advocating straight honesty. If there's anything in my answer I can change or add to better emphasise that point, please let me know or propose an edit.

Answer (score -1):

Yea, the 'international and local wages and my relative position' sounds like a line they feed you to try and justify. I would believe it.

It is possible that the company is struggling and can't afford to pay more. If their costs are being squeezed they may not have scope to pay more. A company would not want to tell their employees this directly so they may use the 'international average' as a way to fob you off.

It is also possible they are being tight. They are trying to get away with paying you as little as possible. The can then go into profits or even bonuses for the line managers.

If you are unable to leave and they will not negotiate the only other thing you can do is ask for a promotion. If you have several years of glowing reports this would seem possible. Perhaps it is time to take on more responsibility and get more wage for doing so. You don't specifically exclude this as an option so it is worth mentioning.